# Please recommend a book regarding Monte Carlo simulation in OAS

Tags: bond, reference-request, valuation

I couldn't find a book that explains in details how to use Monte Carlo Simulation to generate a number of interest rate scenarios. And then based on the interest rate scenarios, how to calculate the OAS to account for embedded options in the bond. I understand the basic idea but I expect to master every detail in this approach.  Thanks so much for your recommendations!